# Python DB-API: how to handle different paramstyles?

Tags: python, sql, python-db-api

I'm implementing a Python ontology class that uses a database backend to store and query the ontology. The database schema is fixed (specified in advance), but I don't know what type of database engine is being used. However, I can rely on the fact that the Python interface of the database engine uses the Python DB-API 2.0 ([PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)). A straightforward idea is to let the user pass a PEP 249-compliant `Connection` object to the constructor of my ontology, which will then use various hardcoded SQL queries to query the database:

```
class Ontology(object):
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection

    def get_term(self, term_id):
        cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        query = "SELECT * FROM term WHERE id = %s"
        cursor.execute(query, (term_id, ))
        [...]
```

My problem is that different database backends are allowed to support different parameter markers in the queries, defined by the `paramstyle` attribute of the backend module. For instance, if `paramstyle = 'qmark'`, the interface supports the question mark style (`SELECT * FROM term WHERE id = ?`); `paramstyle = 'numeric'` means the numeric, positional style (`SELECT * FROM term WHERE id = :1`); `paramstyle = 'format'` means the ANSI C format string style (`SELECT * FROM term WHERE id = %s`). If I want to make my class be able to handle different database backends, it seems that I have to prepare for all the parameter marker styles. This seems to defeat the whole purpose of a common DB API for me as I can't use the same parameterised query with different database backends.

Is there a way around it, and if so, what is the best approach? The DB API does not specify the existence of a generic escaping function with which I can sanitize my values in the query, so doing the escaping manually is not an option. I don't want to add an extra dependency to the project either by using an even higher level of abstraction (SQLAlchemy, for instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the problem is not caused by the DB API allowing this, but by the different databases which use different SQL syntaxes. The DB API module passes the exact query string to the database, along with the parameters. "Resolving" the parameter markers is done by the database itself, not by the DB API module.

That means that if you want to solve this, you have to introduce *some* higher level of abstraction. If you do not want to add extra dependencies, you will have to do it yourself. But rather than manually escaping and substituting, you could try to dynamically replace parameter markers in the query string with the desired parameter markers, based on the paramstyle of the backend module. Then pass the string, WITH parameter markers to the db. For example, you could use '%s' everywhere, and use python string substitution to replace the '%s' with ':1', ':2' etc. if the db uses 'numeric' style, and so on....

Comment: Hmm, I'm not 100% sure about the DB API module passing the exact query string to the database; for instance, `BaseCursor.execute` in the `MySQLdb` module uses `query = query % db.literal(args)` to format the query string explicitly before sending it to the DB engine. This might not be true for other DB engines, though. Anyways, I'm also leaning towards replacing `%s` with other marker styles explicitly, on-the-fly, but I was wondering whether there's a simpler solution. If no one comes up with anything else, I'll happily accept your answer.

Comment: "*The DB API module passes the exact query string to the database, along with the parameters.*" I don't think that's the case at all. If you look at [PostgreSQL's network spec for example](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/protocol-flow.html#PROTOCOL-FLOW-EXT-QUERY), when used, param queries use `$1`, `$2`, ... as place holders, which aren't any of the [Python paramstyles](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle). Clearly, query strings are modified before being sent, one way or another, more so when using a param style that relies on a dict (with names).

Answer (score 7):

- [This Python recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/278612-single-parameters-style-for-db-api-modules/) might be able to help. It introduces an extra layer of abstraction to wrap parameters in its own `Param` class.
- The [PyDal](http://pydal.sourceforge.net/) project may also be closer to what you're trying to achieve: "*PyDal makes it possible to use the same paramstyle and datetime types with any module that conforms to DBAPI 2.0.  In addition, paramstyles and datetime types are configurable.*"

Comment: Both of these options look good, but note they seem to be old.  Those source code web pages show latest comments/updates from 2004-2007.  That may be fine.  Just be aware.

Comment: The pyDAL link is outdated, but the project seems to be alive and well, now on GitHub (https://github.com/web2py/pydal).

Answer (score 1):

The thing that tripped me up here was how to figure out what paramstyle is required if your code is just being passed a connection or cursor object. Here's what I came up with:

```
import importlib

def get_paramstyle(conn):
    name = conn.__class__.__module__.split('.')[0]
    mod = importlib.import_module(name)
    return mod.paramstyle
```

You should probably do more sanity checking of the conn object, or at least wrap this up in a `try` block, depending on what assumptions you're willing to make.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to add an extra dependency to the project either by using
>   an even higher level of abstraction (SQLAlchemy, for instance).

That's too bad, because SQLAlchemy would be a perfect solution for this problem.  In theory, DB-API 2.0 is built to offer this kind of flexibility.  But that would require every driver developer (for Oracle, MySQLdb, Postgres, etc) to implement all the different paramstyles in their drivers.  They don't.  So you get stuck with the "preferred" paramstyle for each database engine.

If you refuse to use SQLAlchemy or any other higher abstraction layer or modern MVC class library, yes you have to write your own higher level of abstraction for this.  I don't recommend that, despite that being your chosen solution here.  You're facing some devilish details there, and will waste time figuring out bugs that others have already solved.

Don't view an external library dependency as a bad thing.  If that's your approach to Python, you are going to be missing out on some of the most powerful features of the language.

Pick your poison.